# How do I get Rainbow 6 Vegas 2 to work with multiplayer on Steam?

Tags: steam, rainbow-six-vegas-2

I bought Rainbow Six Vegas 2, and online play is not working. Looked around the forums and could not find a work around for Steam users.

I bought other ubisoft titles to find out that they are not compatible with Steam.

This game seems to work when purchased from other sources, so how can I get my Steam version to work?

Comment: More like scammed by Ubisoft...

Comment: but the retail version works online. Just steam doesn't. sigh.

Comment: This looks more like a rant than a question, and as such it doesn't really belong on the site. What you could have done is described your problem in detail and provided useful information like a link to the relevant forum discussions you came across, in hope that someone has faced a similar problem and has information to share.

Comment: well I am looking for ways to fix this problem. hence, I am still open to answers.

Comment: I may have cleaned up your question slightly.  Feel free to correct any inaccuracies I introduced or rollback as you feel is necessary.

Comment: Nicely done @tzenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: It would be nice if you added a more details error description (error message? servers listed or not? timeout at connection to the server? etc.).

Depending on you country you'll the CUT or the UNCUT version of the game by Steam. CUT and UNCUT version are incompatible (at least at the time i played); so you can't play with a CUT version on an UNCUT server and vice versa. There will be probable no servers left for the UNCUT version. There are patches out there to convert a CUT version to UNCUT (just google for "rainbox 6 vegas 2 uncut patch").

Another widespread problem is that some routers require configuration. You have to open these ports;

TCP: 3074 to 3174 + 10130 (in- and outgoing)

UDP: 10140 (in- and outgoing)